# How often should you redesign the user interface of a mobile app (non-consumer)?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, mobile-application, redesign, enterprise

Is there a published best-practice or recommendation for how often the user interface of a mobile app (professional/enterprise not consumer) should be totally redesigned?  If so, could someone please provide a reference.

Comment: I see many huge websites being redesigned once every 2 years at list: Gmail, facebook, twitter...

Comment: Not a study but I implore you not to redesign just because of some time-frame quota, if you're redesigning hopefully you're doing it because your user testing and feedback has given you improvements you want to implement

Comment: You should redesign it when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of UX, you should redesign when necessary, and that should be continuously.

That's not to say you redesign the entire site continuously but rather you constantly redesign and improve the user experiences that make up the site.

Sometimes that might be tweaking content on a particular page. Or re-arranging the flow of a wizard based on user feedback. Or changing the button sizes on a screen after doing some user testing.

In other words, ideally, a UX team has the ability to make *continuous improvements* to the site as needed.

From a visual/branding standpoint, the question then becomes one of marketing and advertising more than UX. You don't typically want to redesign the entire site for the sake of having a new look as that's often an annoyance to the user. But there may very well be marketing reasons to do so. Sometimes marketing trumps. :)